# Angular2 - Pipe converting enum form API

Tags: api, pipe, angular, transform

I am working on a project where I want to convert the id's of a enum form the backend to the string form to make it easier understandable for the forntend.

For this i wanted to use a Pipe. 
The pipe should contact the API where it gets a JSON objects with key and value.

My problem is that i cant seem to get the transform function to wait until i have received the api data and stored it in an variable.

I know how to Contact the api and get the object. And i have made a transform that does what i need it to do. I just cant wrap my head around how to get the two to talk together.

Here is what i have for now:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from 'angular2/core';

import {ApiHelper} from '../../services/api.service';

@Pipe({ name: 'userType' })
export class userType implements PipeTransform {

    private typeObject;

    constructor(private ApiService: ApiHelper) {
        ApiService.getAllTypes().subscribe(
            types => this.storeTypes(types)
        );
    }

    storeTypes(types){
        this.typeObject = types;
    }

    transform(value: number, args: string[]): any {
        var userType;

        for(var type in this.typeObject){
            if(type.value == value){
                usertype = type.key;
            }
        }

        return userType;
    }
}
```

Hope someone can help or point me towards the right solution.

____ EDIT: _____

As a newbie this is what i understood from Günter Zöchbauer's answer. 
This returns nothing to my view.

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from 'angular2/core';

import {ApiHelper} from '../../services/api.service';

@Pipe({ name: 'userType' })
export class userType implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(ApiService: ApiHelper)

    transform(value: number, args: string[]): any {

        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
             this.ApiService.getAllTypes().subscribe(typeObject => {

                var userType;
                for (var type in typeObject) {
                    if (type.value == value) {
                        usertype = type.key;
                    }
                }

                resolve(userType);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make code wait for completion of an async call.

I haven't tried building such a pipe that returns a promise myself, but if it can work at all, then return a Promise that completes when the value arrives.

```
transform(value: number, args: string[]): any {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
    http.get(...).map(...).subscribe(value => {
      ...
      resolve(theResult); 
    });
  });
}
```

You might need to use the `async` pipe in addition to your custom pipe.

```
<div>{{item | userType | async}}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks ofr the answer. I tied following your answer, but i jut get an empty result now. Maybe you could see what i do wrong. I added my code to the Question.

Comment: I implemented a simple example. https://plnkr.co/edit/2LupLi?p=preview. Seems to work fine. `| async` is required to make it work.

Comment: I see that the demo works, but it seems that the HTTP does not get fired when inside the Promise.

Comment: I updated the Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/d6iecn?p=preview (fetches some arbitrary URL)

Comment: Nice, i got i working, im not sure exactly what i did, but it works. Thanks :)